# Are these polynomials irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

$$x^3+x^2+x+1$$

$$x^5+x^3+x^2+1$$

$$x^5+x^3+x+1$$

I've tried applying Eisenstein criterion but I can't figure it out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: These are likely to be 3 different questions. There need not be any good reason why the same approach will work for each of them, unless you were told to use Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. Yeah for the last polynomial listed I can just apply the rational roots theorem to see that the only possible roots are -1,1 and can easily see that it has no roots in Q.

Comment: That is not sufficient. It could have a factorization into cubic and quadratic factors, like in the second.

Answer (score 10):

$$x^3+x^2+x+1=(x+1)(x^2+1)$$
$$x^5+x^3+x^2+1=(x^2+1)(x^3+1)$$

For $f(x)=x^5+x^3+x+1$, we have $f(2)=43$, which is prime, so by [Cohn's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohn%27s_irreducibility_criterion), $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: My pleasure.  $~$

Comment: @vadim123: I looked up the Criterion, and it was not clear to me how it was applied.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: It's the part: "The theorem can be generalized to $b\ge2$ other bases as follows:

    Assume that $b \ge 2$ is a natural number and ..." He used the generalization version, not the original one.

Comment: @user49685: Thank you. I had done it the "hard" way, by tracing what the factors must be.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: My pleasure. I'm new to this theorem, too; but it seems beautiful, and should come handy in many situations.

Answer (score 1):

$x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ has a root $-1$, and so does the second polynomial.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped.

Comment: You're very welcome!