# Factor the polynomial into irreducible factors in the field $\mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z_{[x]}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, factoring

I want to factor the $X^5 + X^3 + X^2+1$ into irreducible factors in the field $\mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z[x]}$.

I'm new in abstract-algebra, so I couldn't apply ideas from similar tasks to this one.

So, can someone explain it for me on this case? Looks like I have to brute-forse some roots and then compose their multiplies into $\mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z_{[x]}}$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: We have done this particular polynomial earlier. In other words this is a duplicate. The idea is that  $x^5+x^2$ is a multiple of $x^3+1$ and it is to work with the resulting factorization.

Comment: The first target is not perfect, because it doesn't explain that modulo two we additional have $x^2+1=(x+1)^2$ and $x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2+x+1)$.

Comment: Approach0 is failing me today :-( May be the threads I remember have been deleted?

Comment: The first target I referred to above is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/443852/11619). Using the answers there it trivially follows that the factorization is $(x+1)^2(x^2+x+1)$. Perhaps the easiest way to get started with this is to observe that $x=1$ is a zero, giving us the factor $x-1=x+1$. After division the same thing happens. And again. That quadratic is then irreducible for a quadratic without zeros is irreducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^5+x^3+x^2+1=x^3(x^2+1)+x^2+1=(x^3+1)(x^2+1)=$$
$$=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)(x^2+2x+1)=(x+1)^3(x^2+x+1).$$
$x^2+x+1$ is irreducible because $1$ and $0$ are not roots of this polynomial.